# Ruby/Rails Command to get details on the app enviorment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, web-applications, rubygems

I am working on a web application running on `Rails 2.1` version.

I would like to know if there is any single command in rails or ruby that could fetch me in the console, all the `details about my application` like the version of my back end DB, Rails, Ruby and all relevant information pertaining to my web app.

This would help me to get all necessary details of my application without having to explicitly
look into each of the details one by one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can try the `ruby script/about` command for your rails app. This must work for the `Rails 2.1` version.

Running this in the console would give you major environment details about your web application. Something similar to this :

Go to the app directory and run the command

```
$ ruby script/about

About your application's environment
Ruby version              1.8.7 (i486-linux)
RubyGems version          1.8.11
Rails version             2.1.2
Active Record version     2.1.2
Action Pack version       2.1.2
Active Resource version   2.1.2
Action Mailer version     2.1.2
Active Support version    2.1.2
Edge Rails revision       e0a2f6c625d99d68df432a3c3418f4217bd56cbf
Application root          /home/path/app_folder  #path of your app directory
Environment               production
Database adapter          mysql
Database schema version   20101110130106
```